# Java 10 var and capture variable

Tags: java, java-10

I'm reading the [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) but I don't understand this part:

> Capture variables, and types with nested capture variables, are
>   projected to supertypes that do not mention capture variables. This
>   mapping replaces capture variables with their upper bounds and
>   replaces type arguments mentioning capture variables with bounded
>   wildcards (and then recurs). This preserves the traditionally limited
>   scope of capture variables, which are only considered within a single
>   statement.

Can anyone make me a concrete example in Java code of what it meaning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`var` allows you to infer a non-denotable type:

```
var x = new Object() {
    int i = 10;
};

System.out.println(x.i); // works; `x` has the non-denotable type of the annonymous class
```

So theoretically that would allow you to infer a wildcard type. But what this text is saying is that that is not possible, because the wildcard is replaced by it's upper bound, or by a new capture variable in the inferred type.

Take for instance this snippet of code:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add("Hello");
List<?> l2 = l1;

var x = l2.get(0);
l2.add(x); // error
```

Here, instead of the type of `x` being inferred to the exact type of the wild card, which would make the last line compile. Instead it is inferred to it's upper bound, which is `Object`, and you get the (Eclipse) error message:

```
The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

Where you can see that the type of `x` is `Object`.

That is the part

> This mapping replaces capture variables with their upper bounds

---

The second part

> ... and replaces type arguments mentioning capture variables with bounded wildcards

Is talking about a situation like this:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add("Hello");
List<?> l2 = l1;
var l3 = l2; // type of 'l3' is List<?>, but not the same '?' as 'l2'

l3.add(l2.get(0)); // error
```

This doesn't compile either, because the type of `l3` is not the exact same type as the type of `l2`, which means that the type returned from `l2.get(0)` is not the same type as required by `l3.add(...)`. The error here is:

```
The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#3-of ?)
```

And you see that both of the capture variables are distinct, meaning that the type of `l3` is not exactly the type of `l2`, but the capture variable of the type of `l2` in the inferred type is replaced by a wildcard with the same bound, for which a new capture variable is then created.

So for a type `List<capture#1-of ?>` the inferred type is `List<?>`, and then the compiler creates a new capture variable for that wildcard, yielding `List<capture#2-of ?>` (though the numbering might work differently in practice, the key is that the 2 capture variables are different).

Comment: Very good explaination! For this "and types with nested capture variables"? Some example?

Comment: @xdevel2000 `List<?>` is a type with a nested capture variable. So for `List<capture#1-of ?>` The super type that is being projected to is `List<?>` (with a wildcard), for which the compiler then creates a new capture variable.

Comment: I think that examples such as `var x = l2.get(0); l2.add(x);` would still fail to compile even without this rule, because the JLS requires that a "fresh" capture variable is created every time capture conversion occurs ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)). The errors would just look like `The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#1-of ?)`, the same as what happens when you try to do something like `l2.add(l2.get(0))`.

Comment: @Radiodef The spec seems to talk about cases where you convert to a denotable type: _"from a parameterized type G<T1,...,Tn> (§4.5) to a parameterized type G<S1,...,Sn>"_ where the idea behind `var` is that it infers the type of the assigned value, so technically, there would be no conversion I think. But it's confusing any ways, so the JEP text is there to clear up this corner case.

Comment: Wildcards aren't proper types (they don't have members, subtypes, supertypes, etc.), so capture conversion turns them in to a type variable any time they are used as a type. In a case like `l2.add(x)`, capture conversion happens when searching the members of the type of `l2` ([the members of a `List<?>` are the members after capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.2)) and in a case like `l2.get()`, [capture conversion is specially applied to the return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3).